# Как написать заголовок столбца в csv-файле на С#

Tags: c#, csv

Записываю полученные данные в csv - файл, как написать заголовки столбцов "*ID*", "*ФИО*", "*Статус*"?

Использую следующий код :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(resp);
                var points = doc.Descendants("user");
                foreach (XElement curent in points)
                {
                    string a = curent.Element("uid").Value;
                    string b = curent.Element("first_name").Value;
                    string c = curent.Element("last_name").Value;
                    string d = curent.Element("online").Value;
                    pad.WriteLine(a + ";" + b + c + ";"+ d);
                }
```

Comment: `pad.WriteLine("ID,ФИО,Статус"); foreach(...`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [c# Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / Сsv файлы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте запись заголовка перед циклом.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(resp);
var points = doc.Descendants("user");
pad.WriteLine("ID;ФИО;Статус");
foreach (XElement curent in points)
{
    string a = curent.Element("uid").Value;
    string b = curent.Element("first_name").Value;
    string c = curent.Element("last_name").Value;
    string d = curent.Element("online").Value;
    pad.WriteLine(a + ";" + b + c + ";"+ d);
}
```