# Заголовки столбцов CSV

Tags: php, csv, open-office

Есть модуль, успешно выгружающий данные из MySQL в файл в CSV-файл
Первая строка файла - заголовки столбцов
Пример выгрузки
`date;time;data_collumn1;data_collumn2;data_collumn3
"2017-10-17";"00:00:00";"5320.ea1744e16a5be392be888f7caa9de2ae";"lorem ipsum";"lorem ipsum"`

При открытии некоторых, экспортированных из других источников, CSV ранее OpenOffice-Calc автоматически определял, что первая строка является набором названий для столбцов таблицы

Сейчас же это не происходит, что вызывает необходимость лезть в параметры, закреплять строку или использовать какие-то другие подходы, отнимающие время

Данные записываются вот так

```
fputcsv($this->outputFile, $data,';');
```

Ещё пробовал вариант

```
fputs($this->outputFile, '"'.implode('";"',$data).'"'.PHP_EOL);
```

Заголовки склеивались без кавычек, пробовал разделители: `,;`

Если что

1. Гугл и поиск по Stack Overflow(на обоих языках) не помог найти объяснение
2. Есть [страница решения на C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512766/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-csv-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%A1), но я не вижу отличий от того, что происходит у меня
3. В справке OpenOffice нет ответа

Comment: а вы пробовали записать скриптом эталонные данные. И те же данные самому забить вручную в calc и вручную эспортировать. А затем сравнить два файла?

Comment: @n.osennij Проблема в том, что я даже не могу найти, как через Calc задать заголовки столбцов

Comment: Так не задавайте. Это невозможно сделать для scv. Просто при импорте\чтении принимают, что заголовок есть или его нет. Попробуйте указать для полей заголовка тип. Например `movieId:ID,title,year:int,:LABEL`. Возможно так удастся указать,что первая строка заголовок.

Comment: @n.osennij не прокатило
Calc автоматически распознаёт типы данных в колонках

Comment: Тогда даже и не знаю...